# Websocket communication between two windows

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have this simple code:

```js
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000', ['soap', 'xmpp']);

connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping');
};


connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};


connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};
```

I think, when I open this page in two different windows on my PC, in console I will see ping from other window?

Fore example I see in console 'Ping'.
When I open my script in other browser/tab I will see another 'Ping' in my first window.
Is it true or it need server part?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a peer-to-peer connection between clients. Websockets does not provide this service. To implement this using websockets, you will need to configure the server to relay messages between clients. I would suggest looking at [WebRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC), which provides mechanisms for peer-to-peer communication between browsers.